# Check for User-Input in Batch-Script

Tags: c#

Iam currently starting batch-script with this method (async)

```
private void executor(string path)
{
    //Vars
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process;

    processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process = Process.Start(processInfo);

    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) => 
    {
        //Handle Output
    });

    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        //Handle Errors
    });

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

    //Handle Exit
}
```

The user chose the script (which will be performed by my program) and can run it. But the user can chose a script, which contains a `pause`-Command.
This will cause a deadlock.
How can I check that the script need a user-input?

Comment: I don't think you can determine that.  Is this batch file run in the background, or console window?

Comment: In Background. But, I showing the last flushed lines from the script.
But "Press a key" triggers not the ´OutputDataReceived`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Iam not longer use the `OutputDataReceived`-Event.

Here is my new (well-working) code:

```
 private void executor(string path)
 {
    //Vars
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process;

    processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process = Process.Start(processInfo);

    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        //Handle Errors
    });

    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    //Try read while script is running (will block thread until script ended)
    while (!process.HasExited)
        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            char c = (char)process.StandardOutput.Read();


            if (c == '\n')
            {
                _outputList.Add(_lastOutputStringBuilder.ToString());
                _lastOutputStringBuilder.Clear();

                //Handle Output
            }
            else
                _lastOutputStringBuilder.Append(c);

        }

    //Handle Exit
}
```

With this code, I can store the last line (which must not end with a linebreak) and can check it for lines like "Press a key ..."